# Finding what jars are in the classloader for a specific application in tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat6, classloader

**Scenario**

I have a situation where spring is finding two versions of a class.

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:`

My problem is finding where the duplicate class is coming from.

Usually, I'd just use [jdgui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) to open/de-compile all jars in the web-inf/lib and tomcat/lib folders and do a type search for the duplicate class.

The trick is that I am using sysdeo plugin with eclipse, and maven, and several war projects, so things are a little more complex than that.

**My Question**
Is there any GUI or open source library that I can use to find the location of jars for a particular class that works with *Tomcat6*.

In the past, I have used a very nice tool with IBM Websphere's administration console that allows me to browse the classloader tree.

Failing advice from my peers, I guess I'll need to write something myself.

Comment: That's a duplicate *object* you have there, not a duplicate *class*. Check your Spring bean config.

Comment: Hmm. I'll check when I get back into work. My guess is that the module with my spring config is being added to the war, and then sysdeo is adding the target/classes folder. Hence effectively two duplicate spring configs on the class path triggering annotation scanning twice, and thus two objects.  My question still stands on visualizing the class loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help in comments, I was able to come up with the following solution.

The module with my spring config is being compiled into to the war's lib folder (i.e. /target/xxxx-war/WEB-INF/lib/myspringmodule.jar)

Sysdeo tomcat folder is configured to add the /myspringmodule/target/classes to the classpath, thus allowing me to simply re-compile in eclipse. This was effectively adding two duplicate spring configs on the class path triggering annotation scanning twice, and thus two objects.

My solution is to create a maven profile for local builds in eclipse that I use to exclude the two jars.